# Parallel For.Inserting values to excel

Tags: c#

I've recently optimized my function which insert some values to excel workbook with Parallel For loop(i have to compare about 500000 values in the loop). If i use simple for loop everything works good for me, but if i start to use Parallel For statement, i have no mistakes and code works fine, but values are inserted not as expected in excel workbook (in different rows, not like when i use simple for loop).

This is my code sample, can you help me please, to find a solution.

```
Parallel.For(0, DestinationListIDArray.Count, (int i) =>
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < SourceListIDArray.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (DestinationListIDArray[i].ToString() == SourceListIDArray[j].ToString() && DestinationListIDArray[i].ToString() != "НД")
                        {
                            int c = 1;
                            int summ = i + c;
                            string forB = summ.ToString();
                            string forC = summ.ToString();
                            DestrangeH = myExcelWorksheetDestination.get_Range(TEXTBOX_FIO_DESTINATION.Text + forB);
                            DestrangeI = myExcelWorksheetDestination.get_Range(TEXTBOX_DEST_DOLZHNOST.Text + forC);


                            DestrangeH.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(COLORDIALOG_INF1_BACKGROUNDCOLOR.Color);
                            DestrangeH.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(COLORDIALOG_INF1_FOREGROUNDCOLOR.Color);
                            DestrangeI.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(COLORDIALOG_INF2_BACKGROUNDCOLOR.Color);
                            DestrangeI.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(COLORDIALOG_INF2_FOREGROUNDCOLOR.Color);

                            //DestrangeH.set_Value(Missing.Value, SourceArray[j - 2].ToString());
                            //DestrangeI.set_Value(Missing.Value, SourceArray[j - 1].ToString());

                            DestrangeH.set_Value(Missing.Value, SourceListFIOArray[j].ToString());
                            DestrangeI.set_Value(Missing.Value, SourceListDolzhArray[j].ToString());

                        }

                    }


                });
```

I am using a List arrays and i read somewhere that List generics is not thread safe, may be it makes me in trouble. If so can you advice me please what kind of dinamic array to use and how to lock before insert. thanks..

Comment: I don't think Excel COM API is thread safe. Even if it was, you are talking to single excel instance which has to serialize it and thus making your parallel unnecessary.

Comment: You mean that i cannot use a parallelism with excel at all?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so.

Answer (score 4):

Just as I recalled. Read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sesy69e.aspx

TL;DR

Office object model is not thread-safe. You can use multiple threads in certain scenarios, however the COM server serializes the calls for you.

You can't gain anything from using Paraller.For here.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I have read the link above and i think i don't have a proper solution for my scenario.